# How add permissions to web.config in installer

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis, web-config

I am creating a `.exe` to install my MVC application on to client's servers. It downloads zip file from the internet, extracts all files into the correct places, updates the `web.config` file to include all the correct app keys.

The problem that I am having is that IIS doesn't have permissions to read `web.config` so I get a `HTTP Error 500.19`.

I know that I can just give instructions to the installer that tell them to add the permissions manually, but that looks a bit cheap.

So, in C#, what can I do at the end of my installer to allow IIS to read my `web.config` file and really everything else in my site.

Comment: What user account does your installer run under when it's installing the site on the web server ?

Comment: Make sure you post a real question. Do you want to fix the 500.19 issue or something else?

Comment: @sh1rts I only allow the user to run as an Administrator.

Comment: @LexLi I apologise that I did not use a question mark. I shall try and make this as real as possible for you. What can I do at the end of my installer to allow IIS to read my web.config file and really everything else in my site?

Answer (score 0):

> I know that I can just give instructions to the installer that tell them to add the permissions manually, but that looks a bit cheap.

I dont really think that this is a bad idea. All webfiles must be accessable from the user `IIS_IUSRS` of the local server/computer. If they dont have this permission, you get access problems like you state it above.

I suggest you to take a look on the `FileSecurity` class of C#. You will be able to set file permissions, even if it´s only for the `web.config`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm having a look at File Security now. Should this allow me to programmatically add IIS_IUSRS to all of my webfiles?

Comment: Yes it should! But you must be sure that IIS is installed on the target server.